# Approach for using AutoMapper in Business Layer .net core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I have 2 layers in my Application . A API .net core 2.1  and business layer which is a .net core class library .I want to place the automapper profiles in the business layer so that all the mappings are made in the business layer.

I have  included the  services.AddAutoMapper(); in the startup.cs of API project  and placed the profiles in the Business layer. I have referred my business layer in my API layer. The profiles are getting loaded properly but the downside of this approach is, business layer now  has dependency on AutoMapper

Is there any other way to achieve automapping in multiple projects.

Comment: That's the intended usage. Anything else you have to implement yourself through extra indirection.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.